# How to clear 3 double quotes from some rows of a csv file in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3

My csv files in S3 look like this. I want to remove all double quotes from each cells.

```
f_name , l_name, add, phone

"JOE", "DON", """, "1234"

"JOE", "DON", """, "1234"

"SID", "SIR", "", "456"

"SID", "ABC", "A", "456"
```

I have read this csv from from pandas

```
body = object.get()['Body'].read()
reader = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), delimiter=',', quotechar='"',encoding='utf8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
```

but rows having 3 """ are causing problem and i am not able to clear/Parse this. Can you please help me out.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHdTq.png)

Comment: If you don't want to use python to replace the wrong quotes then you can use: `sed -i 's/"""/""/g' your_file.csv`

Comment: Actually we have more than 1000 csv files in a folder so wanted to automate these this through loop. As of now python is the only option i have.

Comment: Then you can apply the same regular expression using python, just after you read the file content in the body var. Here's an example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 1):

As a very basic approach (relying on pandas) you could read the data without providing the quoting option which will ensure having the `"` chars in your data. These chars can then be removed by applying the `.replace()` method on each cell item via `.applymap()`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data_string = '''
f_name , l_name, add, phone
"JOE", "DON", """, "1234"
"JOE", "DON", """, "1234"
"SID", "SIR", "", "456"
"SID", "ABC", "A", "456"
'''

print(data_string)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string), delimiter=',')
print(df)

cleaned = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
print(cleaned)
```

Giving a final output of:

```
        f_name      l_name  add     phone
0       JOE         DON             1234
1       JOE         DON             1234
2       SID         SIR              456
3       SID         ABC     A        456
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change triple-" into double-" before read in dataframe, you can use regex sub.

```py
import re

body = object.get()['Body'].read()
body = re.sub(b'"""', b'""', body)
```

Note that search and replace chars are also bytes, as the type of `body` is bytes.